# if condition in where clause in MariaDB

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement, mariadb, case

These are the primary 4 columns in the EMP_TABLE that i'm using.

EMP_NAME 
EMP_ID
EMP_DEPT 
JOIN_DATE

The general requirement is to fetch EMP_DEPT = 'HR' records only. But if EMP_DEPT = 'HR' records are NOT available in the table, then the requirement is to fetch EMP_DEPT = 'DEV' records from EMP_TABLE. The priority is to be given to HR records.

I know it can be achieved using inner queries or union and count. But I would like to know if it is possible using IF or WHEN. I've tried the following query and it doesn't seem to work.

```
select * from EMP_TABLE where if(EMP_DEPT='HR',EMP_DEPT='HR',EMP_DEPT='DEV');
```

Any help on this is appreciated.

Comment: will an employee always have a dev record if there is no hr record , how many records can an employee have?

Comment: Yeah. It is possible that employee can have a DEV record in case there is no HR record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to do this as:

```
select e.*
from EMP_TABLE e
where (emp_dept = 'HR') or
      (emp_dept = 'DEV' and 
       not exists (select 1 from emp_table e2 where e2.emp_dept = 'HR')
      );
```

The first condition returns all rows with `'HR'`.  The second then returns `'DEV'`, but only when there are no `'HR'` records.

You really do not want to use (or even learn) `if()`.  It is a MySQL extension.  The standard for conditional expressions is `case`.

Then, you don't want to include conditional expressions in `where` clauses.  First, it impedes optimization.  Second, most logic can be expressed using `and` and `or`, so it introduces additional "clutter" in the conditions.

Comment: Thanks so much. It works. Can you please brief me on the logic here?

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with a case based on the count of rows with `EMP_DEPT = 'HR'`; if the count is non-zero then return rows with `EMP_DEPT = 'HR'` otherwise return rows with `EMP_DEPT = 'DEV'`.

```
SELECT *
FROM EMP_TABLE
WHERE EMP_DEPT = CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM EMP_TABLE WHERE EMP_DEPT = 'HR') > 0 THEN 'HR' ELSE 'DEV' END
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=654d0c572ac7013720dce39273c50a7a)

Comment: Thanks it works. Is there any other way wherein I can avoid another select statement. My data is very huge.

Comment: @Impromptu_Coder with an index on `EMP_DEPT` the second select (for either Gordon's or my query) should be very fast and should only be executed once as they both have a constant result.